# Search for a string that contains numbers python

Tags: python, regex, string, digits

So I have the following code:

```
cus_str = "show configuration " #intiate router command string variable

with open(var) as config_file: #open file
    for line in config_file: #line by line reading of file
        if '"xe-" + #anynumber + "/" #anynumber + "/" + #anynumber' in line:
            line = line.replace('\n' , '').replace('"' , '').replace(']' , '')     #removes all extra characters
            i = "| except " + (line.split("cust ", 1)[1]) + " " #split the line and save last index (cust name)
        cus_str+=i #append to string
config_file.close()
```

The line: *if '"xe-" + #anynumber + "/" #anynumber + "/" + #anynumber' in line:* Is what I'm struggling with syntax-wise.

I am looking to see if a line in the file contains the following string: "xe-*number*/*number*/*number*" (ex: "xe-6/1/10"). It will always have this format, but the numbers will change. What sort of syntax would I use to do this most efficiently.

Thanks!

Comment: Use python's regular expression module `re`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this.  Regular expressions allow you to specify a pattern of text (though not all patterns can be expressed as a regular expression).  We can then [`compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) that expression into a [`Pattern`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re-objects) object, and use that object to [`search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search) strings for the pattern.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'"xe-\d+/\d+/\d+"')  # \d+ is "one or more digits".  
                                           # Everything else is literal

with open(var) as config_file:
    for line in config_file:
        if pattern.search(line):  # will return a Match object if found, else None
            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for the [Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) library!

Is this number a date? You can restrict the amount of digits.

```
from re import search, compile #Import the re library with search
pattern = compile(r"xe-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}") #Use this pattern to find lines

cus_str = "show configuration " #intiate router command string variable

with open(var) as config_file: #open file
    for line in config_file: #line by line reading of file
        if search(pattern, line): #Returns None if match is not found
            line = line.replace('\n' , '').replace('"' , '').replace(']' , '')     #removes all extra characters
            i = "| except " + (line.split("cust ", 1)[1]) + " " #split the line and save last index (cust name)
        cus_str+=i #append to string
```

The regular expression: `xe-\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}` matches "xe-" followed by 3 groups of digit pairs with a slash separator. Each group of digits can be 1 or 2 characters in length.

[image]

### Sidenotes

- You don't need to close `config_file` since the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-with_stmt) statement does that for you when you exit the block.
- I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish with `cus_str += i` when there is no match for the pattern. As it stands, it will just repeat the same `i` from the previous line, unless you indent that line by 1 level. Or give you an error if the first line doesn't contain the pattern.

Comment: Very nice diagram.  How did you generate it?  I think the original question includes surrounding `""` double quotes, you might want to amend your answer.

Comment: I think the double quotes were part of the pseudocode to show what she wanted done for that line.

Answer (score 0):

You can test a regex with a simple program like with some online tools like https://pythex.org/ , and then make your program, a little sample to point you in the right direction would be:

```
import re

config_file = ["xe-6/1/10", "xf-5/5/542", "xe-4/53/32" ]
rex = re.compile(r'xe-[\d]+/[\d]+/[\d]+')
for line in config_file: #line by line reading of file
    if rex.search(line):
      print(line)

xe-6/1/10
xe-4/53/32
```